# Error while trying to get Paypal token with Paypal set express checkout API

Tags: curl, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've seen some questions like mine but nothing could help me. So I post my problem here and hope someone can help me...

First, notice i'm new with Paypal APIs.

I'm trying to make a curl request to get a token to make a Paypal parallel payment by using Paypal Express Checkout. For moment, i'm just trying to make this in an Unix terminal.

Here are my params (i'm using sandbox) :

```
USER=<caller_user_id>
PWD=<caller_password_id>
SIGNATURE=AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAhUVQMHL2c.Lqcfp8FePSekEg2q8
METHOD=setExpressCheckout
RETURNURL=http://some.url
CANCELURL=http://someother.url
VERSION=93
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=80
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Cotisation
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=sometest@account.tld
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order1
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Order
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=20
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=0
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=Comission
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=someother@account.tld
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order2
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
```

Here is my curl request:

```
curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d USER=mathieu.menut_api1.synerghetic.net &PWD=J9PC5K3EQZFLKLSF&SIGNATURE=AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAhUVQMHL2c.Lqcfp8FePSekEg2q8&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&RETURNURL=http://menutmathieu.fr&CANCELURL=http://google.com&VERSION=93&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=80&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=80&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Cotisation&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=test@test.com&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order1&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=EUR&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=20&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Order&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=20&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=Comission&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=a@a.fr&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order2&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=1
```

And here is the (complete) answer:

```
[1] 6954
[2] 6955
[3] 6956
[4] 6957
[5] 6958
[6] 6959
[7] 6960
[8] 6961
[9] 6962
[10] 6963
[11] 6964
[12] 6965
[13] 6966
[14] 6967
[15] 6968
[16] 6969
[17] 6970
[18] 6971
[19] 6972
[20] 6973
[21] 6974
[22] 6975
[23] 6976
[24] 6977
[2]   Done                    PWD=J9PC5K3EQZFLKLSF
[3]   Done                    SIGNATURE=AiPC9BjkCyDFQXbSkoZcgqH3hpacAhUVQMHL2c.Lqcfp8FePSekEg2q8
[4]   Done                    METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
[5]   Done                    RETURNURL=http://menutmathieu.fr
[6]   Done                    CANCELURL=http://google.com
[7]   Done                    VERSION=93.0
[8]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
[9]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=80
[10]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Order
[11]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=80
[12]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0
[13]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=Cotisation
[14]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=test@test.com
[15]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order1
[16]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=EUR
[17]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=20
[18]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=Order
[19]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=20
[20]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_TAXAMT=0
[21]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=Comission
[22]   Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=a@a.fr
[23]-  Done                    PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=order2
Bender:~ bardyl$ ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
[1]-  Done                    curl -s --insecure https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp -d USER=mathieu.menut_api1.synerghetic.net
[24]+  Done                    L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
```

I really don't understand what is the problem... If I read the error returned, it's just saying the method isn't supported. But when I read the [Paypal documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-parallelPayments/), it's seems i'm using the good one.

So if someone can helps me...

Thanks :)

Comment: Try making the S on SetExpressCheckout capitalized.  You're using setExpressCheckout.

Comment: Thanks. I'd try this before but this change nothing.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the raw request then?  The error is pretty specific, so for one reason or another it's not seeing your value.

Comment: Hmmm...One thing I notice is you have a space after the USER value and before the &PWD.  That should actually result in a Security Header error.  Get rid of that and see what happens, though.  You might also want to compare [my SetExpressCheckout call on my test server](http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal-php-library/samples/SetExpressCheckout.php) to yours.

Comment: Also, with your version, try 93.0 instead of just 93.

Comment: Hmm, nothing more happend with version 93.0. Thanks for your version, I'll compare to mine. But first, i've just tried to run your RAWREQUEST via CURL and this doesn't work. I get the same error I have with mine. Creepy.

Comment: You've got something going on with your cURL calls then.  I don't ever mess with cURL from the command line so I'm not much help there, I'm afraid.

Comment: can you post the complete response along with `correlationid` ?

Comment: What you mean by complete response with ```correlationid```?
I've updated my post with the complete response.

Comment: @AndrewAngell: is it possible to see your source code?

Comment: Yes, that sample is from [my class library](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library).

Comment: I've succeed to run your request this morning. I'm trying to see where is my problem, but I guess we're not doing the same thing. With my code, i'm trying to have two receivers with ```PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID``` and ```PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID```. And I think the problem is there... I just don't know which element of my request is causing the error.